# How can I check for an @ in a regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

I know that `@` symbol is an operator in regular expressions, but I need to check if it is inserted in a word, then I need to check if `@`is present.

How can I write my regular expression?

Actually my reg-exp (in Javascript) is this :

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/
```

I need to grant the possibility ti insert an `@` too.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't think @ needs escaping.

Comment: As @trzyeM- is saying you should try `\@`, `\` is used to escape characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_@]+$
```

or

```
^[\w@]+$
```

Here this will enable you to put in `@` symbol as it is inside the charracter class.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape `@` symbol. It isn't a regex meta character.

```
/^\w*@\w*$/
```

This ensures that the string must contain a `@` symbol.

**OR**

Use a positive lookahead at the start.

```
/^(?=.*@)[\w@]+$/
```

Positive lookahead asserts that that the string going to be matched must contain a `@` symbol.

```
> /^(?=.*@)[\w@]+$/.test('foo@bar')
true
> /^(?=.*@)[\w@]+$/.test('foo909bar')
false
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tF4jD3/2)